# change Symbol in matplotlib in legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I dont want the line my triangle. How to change this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04HYj.png)
I dont have data for the triangle, I just want to say that triangle = ideal

Code:

```
plt.plot([],[],marker= '^' , label='ideal')
```

Thanks guys

Comment: You could change the linestyle: `plt.plot([],[],marke='^',  ls='', label='ideal')`

Comment: that functions. Thanks

Comment: do you know how to add color?

Comment: I think you should read matplotlib's documentation, and do a minimal effort of research. Those are easy information to find.

Comment: yes thank you you are right.

Comment: `plt.plot([],[],marker='^',  ls='', color='cornflowerblue', label='ideal')`.  There is also `markerfacecolor=...` and `markeredgecolor=...` to set different inside and outline colors.